# Express validator Check if the name does not exits in the db to enable creation

Tags: node.js, express

I want a validator to check if the category title does not exist to enable the creation of the category, but if the category exists then forbid the creation.
How do I check that?

This is my model:

```
const CategoryScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  dishes: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId }],
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your middleware.

```js
// if you are passing the category in req.body
const { title } = req.body
const category = await CategoryModel.findOne({title})

// This checks if there exists a category with the given title
if(category){
    // Return a response if the category is present
    return res.status(400).send({message: 'Category already taken!'}
}

next()
```

Comment: I am using express-validator, but your answer gave me my answer. Thanks!